# "Rank-K Correction" of a matrix and significance?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, matrix-rank

Today my studies led me to read about the [matrix inversion lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity), which Wikipedia introduces as follows:

> In mathematics (specifically linear algebra), the Woodbury matrix identity, named after Max A. Woodbury[1][2] says that the inverse of a rank-k correction of some matrix can be computed by doing a rank-k correction to the inverse of the original matrix.

After some searching I couldn't find any explanation of the terminology **rank-$k$ correction**, but I did find a Wikipedia article about the [BFGS algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broyden%E2%80%93Fletcher%E2%80%93Goldfarb%E2%80%93Shanno_algorithm) that uses the same term:

> Instead, the Hessian matrix is approximated using rank-one updates specified by gradient evaluations...  the approximate Hessian at stage $k$ is updated by the addition of two matrices $$B_{k+1} = B_k + U_k + V_k$$ Both $U_k$ and $V_k$ are symmetric rank-one matrices... [and together] construct a rank-two update matrix...

As far as I can tell from these sources, a **rank-$k$ correction** of matrix $A$ consists of the addition of a matrix $B$ of rank $k$ to $A$.

However, it is unclear to me what exactly the reason is for describing matrix addition in this way.  Can someone help me understand the implications and applications of this terminology at a basic level, as well as its importance to optimization problems?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rank updates to a matrix are often performed when new data is acquired and needs to be incorporated into a given model.

For example, in the case of regression, in order to compute the coefficient estimates, $\beta$, of linear model, the Normal equations say that we can compute them as $\hat{\beta} = (X^{T}X)^{g}X^{T}y$.  If we assume that $X \in R^{n \times p}$ has full column-rank, then $(X^{T}X)^{g} = (X^{T}X)^{-1}$.  Now let's say we observe some new samples $x_{n+1},x_{n+2},x_{n+3}... \in R^{p}$, we can define $X^{*} = \begin{bmatrix} X \\ x_{n+1} \\ x_{n+2} \\ ... \end{bmatrix}$.  Rather than explicitly computing $(X^{*T}X^{*})^{-1}$, which might be costly if $p$ is large, we can make use of the matrix inversion lemma to simply update $(X^{T}X)^{-1}$ (which we already have stored somewhere from fitting our original model) with our new samples.